# Unicycle recommendation

Tags: product-rec, unicycle

I know that this is a 'bi'cycle forum, but I'm going to chance it and ask for unicycle buying advice.

What should I look for when buying a unicycle? I probably will do some leisure riding with it, maybe ride it around NYC instead of walking.

Comment: Well there are a few tricycle questions, so unicycle questions should be fine.

Comment: @milesmeow: What kind of riding will you be doing? City riding? Mountain unicycling? Commuting?

Comment: circus riding maybe?

Comment: Some people may not be aware of this, but unicycle riding is quite popular. People have crossed the country on unicycles, and I've heard of unicycle commuting.

Comment: I did not know that! Only place I've seen em is at the circus and venice beach.

Comment: Yea. But they look ***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have been looking around and found [this site](http://www.unicycling.net/buyersguide.htm).  Has a lot of good information.
Talks about:

- type of riding and what configuration works best
- sizing
- big/small wheels (20"/24"/26"/28"/36" typically for adults)
- width of tires (2.5" - 3")
- crank arms (4" - 6" in .5" increments)
- seats
- where to buy

So for me for "all purpose riding" I would need:

- 24" unicycle (based on inseam measurement...check website above for details)
- 5" or 6 crank arms.
- 3" wide tires, for a smoother ride

Comment: Wheel size is really not related to inseam - rather, an appropriate seatpost must be bought, the limit being when there's no longer room for one at all.  Mostly wheel size is determined by use - small for tricks, larger for going places.  Think of a unicycle as a bike permanently fixed in the 1:1 ratio of a hill climbing gear and consider if that implies you'd want a wheel smaller or larger than an everyday bike.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the most important point is that it should be dirt cheap. Particularly if you're like me and try it briefly, find that it's uncomfortable when you have to involuntarily dismount and never reassemble it after a move.

Other than that, large wheeled unicycles are apparently easier to learn on. They are also faster (assuming ungeared), but not as maneuverable.